# Subquery in Yii2 order by and group by

Tags: mysql, yii2

In mysql the query command I am using is this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `storefirmware_updates` ORDER BY 
`old_version` DESC) AS tmp_table GROUP BY store_id
```

I can't find a way how to do this in Yii2 and pass it inside the activeprovider.

I tried something like this:

```
     $subquery = new Query;   
     $subquery->select(["*"]);
     $subquery->from('storelist_update_view')->orderBy('old_version DESC');

     $query = new Query;
     $query->select(["*"]);
     $query->from('storelist_update_view')->groupBy(['store_id' => $subquery]);
```

but I think this is wrong.

Comment: Why do you need the outer query? you need only 1 select -> select * from Table group by store_id order by old_version DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution for this.

```
$subquery = new Query;   
$subquery->select(['*']);
$subquery->from('storelist_update_view')->orderBy('old_version DESC');

$query = new Query;
$query->select(['*']);
$query->from(['table' => $subquery])->groupBy('store_id');
```

Hope this could help someone that'd encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

No need for subquery here:

```
$Query = new Query;
$Query->select('*')
      ->from('storelist_update_view')
      ->groupBy('store_id')
      ->orderBy(['old_version' => SORT_DESC]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the order is not followed